# WPF Datagrid UI shows rows only after window resize

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, reactiveui

I ran into a very weird scenario while updating the datagrid contents based on dropdown selection

I have a combobox and a datagrid and based on the selected combobox item the grids contents will be displayed dynamically.

**Problem:** Initially the datagrid will be empty on load. When I select combobox item the relevant data will be bound to the datagrid but the data is not shown. When I resize the window (which in turn resizes the datagrid) the results will appear.

Here is my code for datagrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          Name="dgSchools"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rdSchools, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Margin="0,5"
          Background="White"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolDetails}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchoolDetail}"
          Height="150"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="School Name" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnSchoolNameClick"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And `SchoolDetails` is `ReactiveList(Of School)` using ReactiveUI

```
Private lstSchools As ReactiveList(Of School)
Public Property SearchResults() As ReactiveList(Of School)
    Get
        Return lstSchools
    End Get
    Set(value As ReactiveList(Of School))
        Me.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(lstSchools, value)
    End Set
End Property
```